# ListPlot Problem -Graphics- returned

Tags: plotting

I am running Wolfram on a Pi-Top (Raspberry Pi 3).

The command ListPlot[{10,9,8,7,3,2,1}] returns -Graphics- and no plot.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the notebook interface or are you running in the terminal?

Comment: ...and if you're using the notebook interface, what happens if you run ``<<Version6`Graphics`​``?

Comment: I can confirm that this runs on a Raspberry Pi 3 without issue when using the notebook interface